# Javascript Regex: Get everything from inside / tags

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

**What I want**

---

From the above `subject` I want to get `search=adam` and `page=content` and `message=2`.

**Subject:**

---

```
/search=adam/page=content/message=2
```

**What I have tried so far**

---

```
(\/)+search+\=+(.*)\/
```

But this is not good because sometimes the subject ends with nothing and in my case there must be a `/`

```
(\/)+search+\=+(.*?)+(\/*?)
```

But this is not good because goes trought the `(\/*?)` and shows me everyting what's after `/search=`

**Tool Tip:**

---

[Regex Tester](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shows me everyting what's after /search=

You used a greedy `.*` that will happily match slashes as well. You can use a non-greedy `.*?`, or a character class that excludes the slash:

```
(\/|^)search=([^\/]*)(\/|$)
```

Here the front and end may be either a slash or the start/end (`^`/`$`) of the string. (I removed the `+`s, as I can't work out at all what they're supposed to be doing.)

Alternatively, forget the regex:

```
var params= {};
var pieces= subject.split('/');
for (var i= pieces.length; i-->0;) {
    var ix= pieces[i].indexOf('=');
    if (ix!==-1)
        params[pieces[i].slice(0, ix)]= pieces[i].slice(ix+1);
}
```

Now you can just say `params.search`, `params.page` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use String.split(), no regex required:

```
var A = '/search=adam/page=content/message=2'.split('/');
```

Note that you may have to discard the first array item using `.slice(1)`.

Then you can iterate through the name-value pairs using something like:

```
for(var x = 0; x < A.length; x++) {
    var nameValue = A[x].split('=');
    if(nameValue[0] == 'search') {
        // do something with nameValue[1]
    }
}
```

This assumes that no equals signs will be in the value. Hopefully this is the case, but if not, you could use `nameValue.slice(1).join('=')` instead of `nameValue[1]`;